# Get random item from array

Tags: php, random

```
$items = Array(523,3452,334,31,...5346);
```

Each item of this array is some number.

**How do I get random item from `$items`?**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Answer (score 583, accepted):

```
echo $items[array_rand($items)];
```

[array_rand()](http://php.net/array_rand)

Comment: Used this inline to randomly pick youtube video from playlist on page load and is working great:
<?php $videos = Array(0,1,2,3); echo $videos[array_rand($videos)]; ?>

Comment: @TimoHuovinen also there might be an alien standing behind you... It doesn't concern the question directly.

Comment: Remember to seed this function with ´srand()´ because of a known bug in PHP that does not seed it automatically.

Answer (score 43):

If you don't mind picking the same item again at some other time:

`$items[rand(0, count($items) - 1)];`

Comment: How would you go about getting a random item when the keys are not numeric?

Comment: …or if they keys are not in order (e.g., if you have `unset` array elements).

Comment: 1. this will work if array comes from `explode` so keys are numeric 2. can be seeded with `mt_srand($num);`

Answer (score 17):

### Use PHP Rand function

```
<?php
  $input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
  $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
  echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
  echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
?>
```

[More Help](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

Comment: Yall are making this more complicated than it has to be... 

How about this...

$to_shuffle = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$shuffled = shuffle($to_shuffle);
$shuffled = $shuffled[0];

print_r($shuffled);

Comment: @GregoryBowers the shuffle function is suppose to return a boolean. so your code won't work.

Comment: <?php
$to_shuffle = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
shuffle($to_shuffle);
print_r($to_shuffle);
?>

Yes, you are right, but this DOES.

Comment: Don't declare $shuffled, shuffle($array) will apply to the original array. $to_shuffle will return a new shuffled array. So you are correct. This does work though.

<?php
$to_shuffle = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
shuffle($to_shuffle);
print_r($to_shuffle);
?>

Answer (score 10):

use `array_rand()`

see php manual -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php