# set a random string for a variable in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get random item from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233407/get-random-item-from-array)

I need a code to set a random string for a variable.
of course I have the string and they are not generated.
I can put the strings in the array

```
$strings= array('one', 'two', 'yes', 'no', 'yeaa');
$random_str = ????
```

I need $random_str to be one or no or maybe two.
Totally randomly from $strings.

rand and shuffle function didn't do that for me simply, and I'm beginner in php, so I need your help.
so thank you guys for helping me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to get a random element from an array:

```
$strings= array('one', 'two', 'yes', 'no', 'yeaa');
$random_str = $strings[array_rand($strings)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use the rand() function.

```
$strings= array('one', 'two', 'yes', 'no', 'yeaa');
$random_str = $strings[rand(0,4)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<?php

mt_srand(time() * 1000);

$strings= array('one', 'two', 'yes', 'no', 'yeaa');
$ramdom_str = $strings[mt_rand(0, sizeof($strings)-1)];

?>
```

[mt_srand](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php) and [mt_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) are better implementations of rand and srand