# How to pass a Jquery random value to another point in the script?

Tags: jquery, random, var

I want to program a random script for Jquery but I don't know how to pass the values to another point in the script:

```
$(function() {
    var value = ["001", "002", "003"];
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * value.length);
    // ...
});
```

If I would replace now "original value", for example, "20px" through "value[rand]" would emerge there the random value when the script is executed. Unfortunately it only works if I use the original values but not with value[rand]. I have searched already a long time but I can't find the answer, please can anyone help? Many Greetings

Comment: Post your entire script..

Comment: are you asking about the another function?

Comment: No, I asked about the Islam enALI!

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ambiguity as to what you want so please post the entire code.
This might be something that you are looking for [Get random item from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233407/get-random-item-from-array)