# array_pop function pops two elements of the array

Tags: php, arrays, debugging, shuffle

> Nothing wrong with the code it works fine but on some templates not.

Here   is how it works:

I store an array of templates into session and shuffle them only if the session is empty. Each time the page is reloaded, i pop an element of the session. So each time a template is included in the page, it pops out from the array

The issue here, on some templates the `array_pop` function pops 2 elements of the array on page reload (the included template + an other one).

I have tried to delete some code on the "problematic" templates but i cannot find a solution.

I need some help how to identify this issue.

```
session_start();
$templates = array("t1.php","t2.php","t3.php"); #list of templates paths

if (!isset($_SESSION['templates']) || empty($_SESSION['templates'])) {
    shuffle($templates); #shuffle them 
    $_SESSION['templates'] = $templates; #store them in sesssion
}

$currentTemplate = array_pop($_SESSION['templates']); #pops one on each page reload

include $currentTemplate; #includes the next template of the array
#on each page reload an element will be popped out and the next one will    be included, the issue, is that sometimes two elements-templates are popped out of the array.
```

I detected that it pops two elements by the below code:

```
    foreach($_SESSION['templates']  as $key=>$value)
        {
 echo 'The value of session['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
        }
```

**Not reload**

The value of session['0'] is 't3.php'

The value of session['1'] is 't2.php'

**Reload 1:**

> On some templates my code works fine, i repeat. I don't know what is going on :)

Comment: You know that `array_pop()` changes the original array, right? It returns the value _and removes it from the array_.

Comment: You need to show what is not working and how you think it is popping 2 and/or some debugging.

Comment: @AbraCadaver i updated my code to make you understand better. Note that the code is fine, this only happens on some templates and i need help how to identify the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit #3 - After offline discussion**

Turns out JS was initiating a 2nd request (in the background) to the PHP script which was decrementing the stored templates in the session.

Specifically, it was the *preloader* which was looping over images that initiated the extra request to index.php.

```
img = document.images;
jax = img.length;

for(var i=0; i<jax; i++) {
    console.log(img[i].src);
}
```

> 11:38:39.711 VM322:5 http://plrtesting.herokuapp.com/index.php **This one
>
> 11:38:39.711 VM322:5 https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtQqE.gif

**End edit**

The code is doing exactly what you're telling it to do.

> `$currentTemplate = array_pop($_SESSION['templates']);`

You are **removing**, not retrieving, the final element and assigning it to your variable. Each time you reload the page it is `popping` 1 element off the array. That is why you are seeing it reduced over time.

You need to **retrieve** it instead. If you want the last element then:

```
session_start();
$templates = array("t1.php","t2.php","t3.php"); #list of templates paths

if (!isset($_SESSION['templates']) || empty($_SESSION['templates'])) {
    shuffle($templates); #shuffle them 
    $_SESSION['templates'] = $templates; #store them in sesssion
}

$currentTemplate = end((array_values($_SESSION['templates'])));
```

**Edit #1 - Make it shuffle on every page load**

Note that there are multiple ways to randomize the template. Take a look at this way - [Get random item from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233407/get-random-item-from-array?answertab=votes#tab-top).

```
session_start();
$templates = array("t1.php","t2.php","t3.php"); #list of templates paths

// Commented out the if statement so it shuffles on each page load.
//if (!isset($_SESSION['templates']) || empty($_SESSION['templates'])) {
shuffle($templates); #shuffle them
$_SESSION['templates'] = $templates; #store them in sesssion
//}

$currentTemplate = end((array_values($_SESSION['templates'])));

var_dump($currentTemplate);
```

**EDIT #2 - Not sure if it is clear or not but your code is looping over the *remaining* elements; not the popped element.**

Comment: I tried this but the template is static, it does not pop on each reload and the templates do not shuffle

Comment: That is because you are only `shuffle` on the first page-load when the session is empty. On subsequent page loads, the session is set already so it doesn't go into your `if` statement.

Comment: I will edit my answer to make it `shuffle` on every page load.

Comment: yes i noticed on my code, that when the array is empty. E.g. when all the templates have been popped, it is popping 1 element.

Comment: **It is NOT popping 2 elements. It is ALWAYS ONLY removing/popping 1 element. When you first start it is removing 1 from 3 which leaves 2 behind, and then you are looping of the 2 remaining elements. Then you reloaded again and it removed 1 from 2 which leaves 1... and so forth. Not sure if it is clear or not but your code is looping over the **remaining elements; not the popped element.

Comment: By the way i only want it to shuffle when the array is empty. I want to see all templates before shuffling again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170631/discussion-between-gragas-incoming-and-waterloomatt).

Comment: I found the issue. i can't believe it was Javascript preloader. I will add the code in the discussion chat that was included in the template and was causing the issue.