# How to make a html page pick a random title on load?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm new to web development and can't seem to find this specific task anywhere on this site, only things related to dynamic changes while using a page. Basically, I want the contents of the  tag in my  part of my html document to always be different when loading/refreshing the page; I want to store some kind of array of strings in JS, and have the page, upon loading the html, pick one of these strings to insert into the  tag.

This will result in every time I refresh the page, the title on the tab is different, and will not change unless I refresh again.

Can anyone point me to how I might do this? Completely stuck, and out of ideas after my window.onload didn't work.

EDIT: I have tried this code based on what I found on this site, but the title didn't change; and I'm not sure why.

```
var titles = ['rainy skies == best', 'now with more bugs!', 'c > java'];

window.onload = function() {
    document.title = titles[(Math.random() * 10) % 2];
    $('meta[name="description"]').attr("content", 'My website!');
};
```

(This is then linked into the html page as per usual)

Comment: If I need to use PHP, how do I do that?

Comment: It's better to add that into your question along with the `PHP` tag. Also, you'd better show us what you have done so far so we can build on it, thanks.

Comment: Ok. I have tried the following in JS to no avail.

var titles = ['rainy skies == best', 'now with more bugs!', 'c > java'];

window.onload = function() {
 document.title = titles[(Math.random() * 10) % 2];
 $('meta[name="description"]').attr("content", 'My website!');
};

Comment: You know this makes bookmarking/history and breadcrumbing confusing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a little piece of Javascript. It will be executed each time the page loads and can change the page title dynamically.

```
<script>
  var titles = ['asdf', 'qwer', 'uiop']
  var title = titles[Math.floor(Math.random() * titles.length)] // pick random item
  document.title = title
</script>
```

The usage of a backend language like PHP can solve the issue too, but this is much simpler.

Comment: but what if `JavaScript` is disabled on the client side ?

Comment: Hey, thank you. Can I ask why my code in the Q didn't end up working, yet used the same attribute on the document? Its ok if you don't know, I just want to know how to make my code better in future.

Comment: @Jenna try running your code in the browser console and seeing what it returns: `(Math.random() * 10) % 2` outputs `float` numbers which aren't valid array indices.

Comment: `Math.floor` turns them into integers.

Comment: @nicooga yes, but `Math.floor` isn't used in OP's code.

Comment: Return a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive) eg. so for example 0.7271866315023703 * 10 % 2 is a `float`. Array can't contains float numbers as indices

Answer (score 2):

Server-side example. Define a list of titles, pick a random one, and output it in the *title* attribute.

[Get random item from array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4233407/296555)

**PHP**

```
<?php 
    $titles = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']; 
?>

<html lang="">
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $titles[array_rand($titles)]; ?></title>
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `document.title` to change the title in the tab of the website.

```js
const strings = ["bar", "foo", "banana", "apple", "orange", "red", "green", "blue", "brown", "gray"];

window.onload = () => {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * strings.length);
  
  // example with a div
  document.getElementById("my-span").innerHTML = strings[random];
  
  // example with page title
  // document.title = strings[random];
};
```

```html
<span id="my-span"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title id="title"></title>
</head>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var titles = ['rainy skies == best', 'now with more bugs!', 'c > java'];
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * titles.length);
    var titleElement = document.getElementById('title')
    titleElement.innerHTML = titles[random];
}
```

EDIT: innerHTML instead of html